# How to print each for loop value on the table format?

Tags: python

```
for number in range(0,7,1):

    print('Number'f'\nb{number:>2}')

for square in range(0,7,1):
    sqr = (square)*(square)
    print('Square'+f'{sqr:>2}')

for cube in range(0,7,1):
    cb = (cube)*(cube)*(cube)
    print('Cube'f'{cb:>2}')


number square cube 
     0      0    0
     1      1    1
     2      4    8
     3      9   27
     4     16   64
     5     25  125
```

Comment: What do you mean by print each loop on the table format?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print those next to each other to make them look like a table you can replace your code with the below.

```
print('Number\tSquare\tCube')
for i in range(0,7,1):  
    print(i,'\t',i*i,'\t',i*i*i)
```

Output:

```
Number  Square  Cube
0        0       0
1        1       1
2        4       8
3        9       27
4        16      64
5        25      125
6        36      216
```

Comment: I try to use f-string but it's ok too, thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 0


print("number square cube" )
for i in range(0, 11):
   m = i*i
   print(num, '\t', m, '\t', num*m)
   num = num+1
```

oUTPUT

```
Number  Square  Cube
0        0       0
1        1       1
2        4       8
3        9       27
4        16      64
5        25      125
6        36      216
7        49      393
8        64      512
9        81      729
10       100     1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will work fine for you.

Firstly, you have to create a list of all the headings you want and then print those headings.

```py
a = ["Number", "Square", "Cube"]
print("{:>5} {:>5} {:>5}".format(*a))   // * is unzip operator. In case you dont know.
```

Then you will iterate over specific range and print the numbers.

```py
for i in range(0,7):
    print("{} \t {} \t {}".format(i, pow(i, 2), pow(i, 3)))
```

Here's the complete code.

```py
a = ["Number", "Square", "Cube"]
print("{:>5} {:>5} {:>5}".format(*a))
for i in range(0,7):
    print("{} \t {} \t {}".format(i, pow(i, 2), pow(i, 3)))
```

Output:

```
Number Square  Cube
0        0       0
1        1       1
2        4       8
3        9       27
4        16      64
5        25      125
6        36      216
```